# jquery on change at span id want to insert whole select box

Tags: jquery

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/4yp9k81w/9/

Here is html

```
<span id="span_upper_level_name">

<select name="upper_level_id0" id="upper_level_id0" class="upper_level_id" >
<option value="select1">Select1</option>
<option value="2">Transport</option>
</select>

<select name="upper_level_id1" id="upper_level_id1" class="upper_level_id" >
<option value="select2">Select2</option>
<option value="4">Cars</option>
</select>

</span>

<span id="span_position_after">Position after</span>
```

Here is jquery

```
$('.upper_level_id').change(function(){    
$('#span_position_after').html( $( '#upper_level_id0' ).html() );    
});
```

If any select box changes, then want to insert certain select box in `span_position_after`.

But i can insert only words/options of the select box (can not insert drop down box).

How to insert drop down box in `#span_position_after`?

Comment: What in detail do you want to insert in the `span`? Do you want to add a `select` with `option`s? Which `option`s?

Comment: Want to insert whole select box. Below answers show what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the `outerHTML` or you could clone it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.upper_level_id').change(function () {
        $('#span_position_after').html($('#upper_level_id0')[0].outerHTML);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yp9k81w/13/)

Answer (score 1):

use `clone()` method  instead of `html()`, `hmtl()` method returns only `innerHTML` of selector element.

```
$('#span_position_after').html( $( '#upper_level_id0' ).clone() );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#upper_level_id0').clone() // duplicate selectbox
                     .attr('id', function(){return this.id + 'after'}) 
                     .attr('name', function(){return this.name + 'after'})
                                      // change ID. don't dulicate IDs!
                     .appendTo('#span_position_after') // append cloned select to span
```